# magento custom states for country

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Im working on Magento latest version .The store is for UK ,I need to add country like Manchester, London, Yorkshire etc..This should show in the shipping setting when I select UK from the dropdown viz :default is USA and also in the shipping and billing address. And the defaut country should always be UK as default
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default country from magento admin->system->configuration->General->country options -> Default Country.
To add regions (counties) for UK I think you have to populate the directory_country_region table.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the official UK translation [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/771/)

Comment: How about for Indian states ?

Comment: @mark here's a guide on how to add the list of Indian states http://dploy.in/2012/adding-states-in-india-to-magento/

Answer (score 2):

I found a post you might appreciate. It concerns the "directory_country_region" tables.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/192387/